# Criação de objetos anônimos vs "nomeados (?)"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, entity-framework, design-pattern

Tenho uma classe que *loga* algumas informações no banco de dados eu estou utilizando ela da seguinte maneira:

```
 new StudyLogRepository().Create(new StudyLog() {
  StudyId = Study.Id,
   CycleId = null,
   DateOccurrence = DateTime.Now,
   CycleActionName = "Nova estudo gerado",
   UserId = int.Parse(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session[SessionKeys.USER_ID].ToString())

 });
```

Porém no mesmo método eu acabo tendo que *logar* diversas informações, então acabo tendo este código duplicado em diversas classes e métodos tornando a manutenção super complicada.

Como posso solucionar este meu problema de código duplicado sendo que os dados a serem *logados* sempre vem diretamente da classe ou do método onde existe esse trecho duplicado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não sei como essa sua estrutura mas é só criar um método utilitário estático em uma classe que faça sentido que retorne isto, algo assim:

```
public static StudyLogRepository BuildStudyLog() => new StudyLogRepository().Create(new StudyLog() {
    StudyId = Study.Id,
    CycleId = null,
    DateOccurrence = DateTime.Now,
    CycleActionName = "Nova estudo gerado",
    UserId = int.Parse(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session[SessionKeys.USER_ID].ToString())
});
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Method/Abstraction.cs).

Pelo que entendi dará erro se o `USER_ID` vier errado. Qualquer coisa que venha externamente precisa ser validado antes de usar. Pode até abrir brechas de segurança.

O mecanismo mais usado para evitar duplicação de código é sempre a função ou método. Você cria uma vez e depois é só chamar para obter o resultado desejado. O mecanismo da função foi criado justamente para isto.

Se conhecesse toda solução talvez tivesse uma maneira melhor de fazer isto.